# Mysql throws error while inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`SALARY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`DEPT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

If i insert value for the above table, like in the below following its throws error

```
INSERT INTO employee ('NAME', 'SALARY', 'DEPT') VALUES ('user test', 10000, 'ADMIN');
```

Comment: If you get an error message, please post it together with your question. Error messages have a purpose: to help diagnose issues. Don't make us guess!

Comment: Yay, a guessing game!

Answer (score 6):

remove the single quote on the column names.

```
INSERT INTO employee (NAME, SALARY, DEPT) VALUES ('user test', 10000, 'ADMIN');
```

Single quotes are for string literals and column name are identifiers. The server throws an exceptions because the columns expects an identifier and not string literals. Wrapping identifiers with single quotes converts it into string.

if it happens that the column names as well as tables names you have are one of the keywords in mysql reserved keywords list, this can be delimited using backticks.

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
INSERT INTO employee ('NAME', 'SALARY', 'DEPT') VALUES ('user test', 10000, 'ADMIN');
```

to

```
INSERT INTO employee (`NAME`, `SALARY`, `DEPT`) VALUES ('user test', 10000, 'ADMIN');
```